# How do I use cfhttp to automatically post to facebook's graph api?

Tags: facebook, oauth, coldfusion, facebook-oauth

I have followed the tutorials/documentation on facebook's site and am one step away from publishing to a user's wall/timeline using coldfusion.  I have one last step, post automatically with cfhttp.  I can't get it to work.

```
<!--- This is the page that you call and also use as the redirect_uri... facebook returns code and state in the URL --->
<cfparam name="URL.code" default="" type="string">
<cfparam name="URL.state" default="" type="string">
<cfif #URL.code# EQ "">
    <cfparam name="URL.error_reason" default="" type="string">
    <cfparam name="URL.error" default="" type="string">
    <cfparam name="URL.error_description" default="" type="string">
    <cfmail charset="utf-8" type="html" server="mail.mysite.com" from="messages@mysite.com" to="messages@mysite.com" subject="Facebook Authentication Denial">
    #SESSION.my_profile_id#: #SESSION.my_profile_username#
    #URL.error_reason#<br/>
    #URL.error#<br/>
    #URL.error_description#<br/>
    </cfmail>
    <cfabort>
<cfelse>
    <cfhttp 
    method="get"
    url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=myappid&redirect_uri=http://www.mysite.com/dbf/_my-controller/fb_user_code.cfm&client_secret=216792f1a1ddbb568c57624a988028dc&code=#Trim(URL.code)#"
    result="my_fb_user_token"/>
    <cfif #my_fb_user_token.filecontent# CONTAINS "access_token=">
        <cfset new_token = ReplaceNoCase(#my_fb_user_token.filecontent#,"&expires","|","all")>
        <cfset new_token = REReplaceNoCase(#new_token#,"\|.*$","")>
        <cfquery name="fb_confusion" datasource="#dsn#" maxrows="1">
        SELECT facebook_id
        FROM my_profile
        WHERE my_profile_id = '#SESSION.my_profile_id#'
        </cfquery>
        <cfoutput>#new_token#</cfoutput>
        <hr/>
        <cfhttp 
        method="get"
        url="https://graph.facebook.com/me?#new_token#"
        result="my_fb_user"/>
        <cfoutput>https://graph.facebook.com/#fb_confusion.facebook_id#/feed?#new_token#</cfoutput>
        <hr/>
        <cfoutput>
        <cfhttp url="https://graph.facebook.com/me/mysite:add?group=http://www.mysite.com/dbf/test_group.cfm&#new_token#"
        result="fb_publish" 
        method="post" 
        multipart="yes">
            <cfhttpparam name="appID" value="myappid" encoded="no" type="url">
            <cfhttpparam name="access_token" value="#my_fb_user_token.filecontent#" encoded="no" type="url">
            <cfhttpparam name="message" value="Test" encoded="no" type="url">
            <cfhttpparam name="link" value="http://www.mysite.com" encoded="no" type="url">
            <cfhttpparam name="name" value="Test" encoded="no" type="url">
            <cfhttpparam name="caption" value="Testing fb api" encoded="no" type="url">
            <cfhttpparam name="description" value="Testing to see if this posts" encoded="no" type="url">
        </cfhttp>
        </cfoutput>
        <cfdump var="#fb_publish.filecontent#">
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

The message returned from the fb_publish dump is:

{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}

Comment: Is your access token valid?  Did you get the token through the proper oAuth Process?

Comment: Yes. The token is valid. I output it in the code above, copy it when its returned, and paste it into facebook's graph debugger and it works just fine.  The issue begins with cfhttp method="post"

Comment: I can't answer until 8 hours... blah.  First of all, the URL in the cfhttp post needs to be changed to what facebook has as their post URL in the tutorial: https://graph.facebook.com/me/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:cook?recipe=OBJECT_URL&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
Next, my params needed to be changed from type="url" to type="formfield".

That's it.  It now works.

Comment: Anger.  Just when I thought I was done... Now I'm getting a new error.  "This action is not allowed to set a user message because this property was not requested for approval" ???

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/affinitiz/facebook-cf-sdk

or try alternate method (dirty method used by me :) )

http://cfmitrah.com/blog/post.cfm/update-facebook-status-using-email-without-graph-api